# Call fortran function from Python with ctypes

Tags: python, fortran, ctypes

I am looking to use ctypes to call some old fortran libraries which were written by my boss a few years ago. I followed the example given in [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811949/call-functions-from-a-shared-fortran-library-in-python), and I get the results as expected.

However, when I modify the code, to get slightly closer to the situation I face, so that

```
integer function addtwo(a, b)
  integer, intent(in) :: a, b
  addtwo = a + b
end function
```

becomes

```
real function addtwo(a, b)
  integer, intent(in) :: a, b
  addtwo = a + b
end function
```

i.e., the function is now `real`, not `integer`, the value returned is always `0`. Can anyone explain what's going on and how I should get around this?

(PS. I'm using a 64-bit gfortran compiler on mac os snow leopard)

*EDIT*: The function I'm struggling with looks like:

```
real function ykr(seed)

  integer, intent(in) :: seed
  real ykr0
  ykr= real(seed)
end function
```

Really, `ykr` calls another function, `ykr0`, recursively, but since I'm struggling even with this basic aspect I'm ignoring that for now. I can't see what's different between this code and the above, but calling `ykr_(byref(c_int(4)))` returns `0`, not `4` as expected...

Comment: Why aren't you using the Fortran FFI stuff that comes with NumPy?

Comment: You mean f2py? It's causing a lot of headaches on my system and I decided this would be a good short-term fix. In theory!

Comment: you could try `addtwo = real(a+b)`, does it fix it?

Comment: that does, but implemented into main code (see edit), and I'm still not getting the expected result. I can't see any difference between those two functions, though.

Comment: this looks interesting http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#return-types

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the line

```
ykr_.restype = c_float
```

in your python code, before `ykr_(byref(c_int(4)))`.
This sets the return type for the function to `float` (or `real` in Fortan language).

In the original post, this was not necessary since int was assumed as default.